# Android: Editext start of text

Tags: android, android-layout

How do i set the starting position of the inputted text in the center or anywhere but not with the leftmost part of the editext. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **android:paddingLeft** property in the xml of EditText to displace the text from leftmost part.

```
android:paddingLeft="10dip" // give value according to need.
```

You can use **android:gravity="center"** too but that will place your text exactly in the middle.

Comment: thanks dinesh! both are working.. but since i need the text to start not exactly in the center.. i used the paddingLeft... Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

use `android:gravity` in your layout file.

i.E.:

```
<EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: thanks mannaz! android gravity is good if you need to start the text in the center.. thanks a lot..